# Laravel - default virtual host wont work (Previously working but not now)

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-5, virtualhost

Hi I installed laravel and it's working fine

my httpd-vhosts.conf is

```
<VirtualHost laravel.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public"
    ServerAdmin laravel.dev
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost taskmanagement.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\taskmanagement\public"
    ServerAdmin taskmanagement.dev
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\taskmanagement">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost wp.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress"
    ServerAdmin wp.dev
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and my hosts file is

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1    laravel.dev
127.0.0.1    taskmanagement.dev
127.0.0.1    wp.dev
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

I had a web page or site under C:\xampp\htdocs\site1\index.php
when I try to open my web site(http://localhost/site1/) 
in browser it shows

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: error

but all my following virtual host sites working fine

> http://localhost/laravel/public
>   
>   http://localhost/taskmanagement/public
>   
>   http://localhost/wordpress

my problem is only default site php, html (no virtual host) - xampp

In my C:\xampp\htdocs has following

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\arunsite\public --> laravel project -working
C:\xampp\htdocs\college\public --> laravel project -working
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public --> laravel project -working
C:\xampp\htdocs\lartest\public --> laravel project -working
C:\xampp\htdocs\taskmanagement\public --> noframework- html site -notworking
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\site1\index.php -->  noframework- html site -notworking
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\site2\index.php -->  noframework- html site -notworking
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\site3\index.php -->  noframework- html site -notworking
.
.
.
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\site50\index.php -->  noframework- html site -notworking
```

Answer (score 0):

When you activate the `v-hosts` configuration the default `localhost` usually gets replaced.

So just add the said entry in `v-hosts`

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\"
ServerAdmin localhost
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Restart `apache` afterwards

Comment: Every Time i need to config VirtualHost  for site1, site2, site3 etc.,?

Comment: No... just once. All the said sites, viz; site1, site2 should be available at `http://localhost/site1`, `http://localhost/site2` respectively.

Comment: before i install laravel i did not create vhost directory like, that time i create site on htdoc it jst run smoothly but after install laravel and config vhost my vhosted sites only wrking. Here i need both old method(normal files run on anywhere on htdoc) as well as vhost site

Comment: I dynomically create and test php site, file and so on. But now i need to create a vhost if i test a single page thats y get irritate

Answer (score 0):

make the entry as suggested by @huzaib and restart apache. You can also check xampp logs for the specific details, if not working share that log line particularly.

Comment: Every Time i need to config VirtualHost for site1, site2, site3 etc.,???

Comment: when ever you are setting up first time you have do else how web server will know from where to serve a particular request.

Comment: chk my comment on above answer